# mobile browser not allowing scrolling

Tags: css, mobile

I just tested my new site with my android phone and I am not able to scroll anywhere on the page. On Firefox, opera, ie, and chrome desktop browsers I get vertical scroll when needed. In my html, body css rule I've got overflow-y to scroll; Width should not be scrolled. I'm probably missing something simple here but I've never come across this in any other sites I've done.

Here's my css for the site:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#body{


    min-width: 900px;
    width: 75%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(../graphics/back2.jpg);   
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #000; 
    background-repeat: repeat-y;    
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;

}
a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    background-image: url(../graphics/craig-smith-background.jpg);
    line-height: 25px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px;
}
 h2{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 20px;
}
h3{
    font-size: 24px;    
    margin: 10px;
}

p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
#quote{
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: lucida;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #333;
    border-width: 2px;
    height: 80px;
}

#header{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

}

#nav{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 25%;

    top: 150px;
    }
.picture{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #999; 
}

.clear-left{
    clear: left;
    position: relative;

}

.clear-right{
    clear: right;
    position: relative;
}

.clear-all{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

#left-col{
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
    text-wrap: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

#right-col{
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 65%;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #CCC;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-wrap: normal;
    text-indent: 10px;

}
#footer{
    width: 85%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #999;
}

#project-description h1{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 36px;
}

.project-description h2{
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;  
}





.project-description{
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #333;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;

}

.project-description p{
    margin-left: 70px;  
    text-indent: 0;
}
table{
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;


}
td, th, tr{
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

And [here's](http://www.craig-smith.comlu.com) a link the live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give the body and html tags the `overflow-y: scroll;` style. That is resulting in a double scrollbar which is failing in mobile browsers. You don't even need to specify that as it is default behavior. You may want to set `overflow-y: scroll;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body tag only.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just moved overflow-y by itself to a new body rule